# create autogenrate column in django admin panel

Tags: python, django

i want to create a column name "cust_id".which is autogenerated how to write code for this code for admin panel. 
**models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
cust_id=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
```

I have written code for autogenerete cust id for views but that code is not working for admin panel 
**code for auto-generate cust id**

```
def create(self, request):

    queryset=Account.objects.all()

    data=request.POST

    temp=queryset.aggregate(Max('cust_id'))
    print temp
    temp=temp.get('cust_id__max')
    print "temp>>",temp

    cust_id=""
    if not temp :
        print"before"
        cust_id="CUST0001"
        print "cust_id=",cust_id
    else:
        print"after"
        print "m=",temp
        prefix=temp[0:4]
        print "prefix",prefix

        suffix=temp[4:]
        print "suffix",suffix

        int_suffix=int(suffix)  

        print "prefix=",prefix,"suffix=",suffix,"int_suffix",int_suffix
        if int_suffix<9 :
            suffix="000"+str(int_suffix+1)
        elif int_suffix>=9 and int_suffix<99:
            suffix="00"+str(int_suffix+1)
        elif int_suffix>=99 and int_suffix<999:
            suffix="0"+str(int_suffix+1)
        elif int_suffix>=999 and int_suffix<9999:
            suffix=""+str(int_suffix+1)


        cust_id=prefix+suffix
        print "cust_id=",cust_id

    account=Account()

    account.cust_id=cust_id
    account.cust_first_name=data.get('cust_first_name')
    account.cust=data.get('cust_address')
    account.is_active=data.get('is_active',default=False)

    if account.save():

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

please check this code.and help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the auto-generator code in the model's save() method instead.

Comment: Or look into its admin form to pre-generate an id as **initial**

Comment: can u please give a short example

Comment: should i write this code in save() method or anywhere else